# Correlacionando valores em Python Arrays

Tags: array, python-2.7

Possuo um vetor chamado POSIÇÃO, com os seguintes valores:

- posicao = [40.51, 30.52, 30.31]

Possuo um vetor chamado COORDENADAS, com os seguintes valores:

- coordenadas = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120]

Cada índice do vetor POSIÇÃO corresponde a outros 4 do vetor coordenadas. Por exemplo:

- posicao = [**40.51**, 30.52, 30.31]

corresponde a:

- coordenadas = [**10, 20, 30, 40**, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120]

Possuo o script abaixo que, ao detectar um valor acima de 40.00 no vetor POSIÇÃO, atribui valores aleatórios nas 4 posições correspondentes no vetor COORDENADAS.

```
import random

posicao = [40.51, 30.52, 30.31]
coordenadas = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120]

for indice in range(0, len(posicao)):
    if posicao[indice]>40:
         for indice2 in range(indice*4, indice*4+4):
            coordenadas[indice2] = random.randrange(0,200) #gerar os aleatorios entre 0 e 200

print(coordenadas)
```

Porém eu desejo que, ao invés de modificar os 4 valores, modifique somente os 2 últimos, por exemplo:

- posicao = [**40.51**, 30.52, 30.31]

Modifique somente:

- coordenadas = [10, 20, **30, 40**, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120]

Como modifico esse código para conseguir isso?

Fico grato aos que puderem me ajudar. Acredito que seja algo fácil, mas não consigo visualizar a solução.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para isso é apenas necessário modificar o segundo `for` para começar 2 elementos a seguir.

Passando de:

```
for indice2 in range(indice*4, indice*4+4):
```

Para:

```
for indice2 in range(indice*4+2, indice*4+4): #Notar no +2 que foi adicionado
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado, mais uma vez!
Funcionou perfeitamente.